# Different random outcomes

Tags: c#, xna

How can i generate different random numbers in short time?
For example:

```
        Number = 20;
        if (Number > 0)
        {
                AddEffect(rand.Next(0,100);
                Number--;
        }
```

In this example, rand.Next gives me twenty times the same number. Is there any way to force a change?

Comment: i have tried your code, and it gives different numbers

Comment: have a `var rand = new Random();` above. It should solve it

Comment: This is so strange because in my code, the Rand is waiting 10 itérations to change its number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to say:

```
var rand = new Random();

var Number = 20;
while (Number > 0)
{
      // rand.Next(0,100); // this will give 20 different numbers btw
      AddEffect(rand.Next(0,100));
      Number--;
}
```

but otherwise, seems fine

Comment: Changing if in while made the job

Comment: well, with the if it only happened once ... i assumes that's what you're trying to do :) glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalNumbers = 20;
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < totalNumbers; i++)
{
   AddEffect(rand.Next(0, 101)); // a number between -1 and 101, min: 0, max: 100
}
```

Is this what you mean? This is an easy and clear way to generate some random numbers.
More info here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Comment: @Pilispring That's true. These two loops do exactly the same.